# add reference to assembly in XSLT C# script block

Tags: c#, xslt, reference, .net-assembly

I'm trying to use a Dictionary in a C# script block embedded in a XSLT1.0 doc.
When I'm trying to add a reference to either System.Collections.Generic or System.Core, I'm getting a 'metadata file not found for assembly...'
When adding ref to 'mscorlib', it seems like an older version is being referenced (?), since I'm getting an error when trying to use Dictionary.Keys.Contains() ('does not contain a Contains method).
Needless to say, this code was tested successfully outside the xslt.
How can I add a proper ref to a FW 3.5/4 ?
Tnx!

Comment: Sharing the critical parts of your source code may help others to dig into your problem. Also, check this: [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dictionary.Keys.Contains` is defined in the `System.Linq` namespace, and Linq is defined in the System.Core assembly, so you'll need the right `msxsl:assembly` and `msxsl:using` elements for those. The following works for me in the VS2013 XSLT debugger:

```
<msxsl:script implements-prefix="my" language="csharp">
  <msxsl:assembly name="System.Core" />
  <msxsl:using namespace="System.Linq" />
  <msxsl:using namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />

  <![CDATA[
    public bool myFunc() 
    {
      var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      d.Add("Hello", "Goodbye");
      return d.Keys.Contains("Hello");
    }    
  ]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

This still leaves the question of why you are using `Dictionary.Keys.Contains`, when you could use `Dictionary.ContainsKey`, which has been in .NET since 2.0 and doesn't need any extra assembly or namespace references.

Comment: Thanks.Using ContainsKey indeed solved the 'no method' issue, however I'm still unable to reference System.Linq, Collections.Generic or Core. Any ideas? VS2010 btw